# Disable color-cycling in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highchart diagram, and I dynamically change data in it by removing all series and adding new. This all works fine, but the problem is that the colors of the bars/columns/lines/etc. changes in a cyclic fashion when I do that. I want the first bar/column/line to always be the first color, the second bar/column/line be the second color, etc.

Is there a way to disable this cycling color, so the colors are static when I remove and add series?

A possible solution I've been thinking about is to set the colors for each series, and keep track of which color to use manually. Unfortunately the code-base is designed (or rather, evolved) in a way that I must change the code in many places for this to work, as the creation of the different charts is done in different places. The main part can be handled in a function, but we must still keep track of which color to use for which chart, as well as set it up on each chart-creation.

Comment: Highcharts doesn't provide such logic (first series of x-type to get one color, second type - second color etc.) If you have always the same number of series, then set [colors](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors) option. If not, I would try to get actual colors: `var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors` and then when adding series, check if series is first of it's type. If it's first of a type, then just use `series.color = colors[0]`. If this is second of a type, use `series.color = colors[1]`.

Comment: In most cases it wouldn't be a noticeable difference in performance to destroy the chart and rebuild with the new data rather than remove/add the series.  This would stop the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Pawel Fus got me on the right track, but it didn't work out of the box. I have to call the [`Series.update`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) function to actually *change* the color:

```
series[x].update({color: series[x].color});
```

Answer (score 0):

for highcharts-ng

```
var colorPalette = ["#007298", "#65cce9", "#f56e00", "#5e4565", "#a5a5a5", "#00ae79", "#0a2f5d", "#ffbd06",'#058DC7'];
```

after data series update:

```
$scope.chartName.series = newData;
var l = colorPalette.length;
for (var i=0; i<$scope.chartName.series.length; i++){
  var l = colorPalette.length;
  $scope.chartName.series[i].color = colorPalette[i%l];
};
```